# How to make a dynamic key optional with typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to make the dynamic key `item` optional. Adding `?` creates an error.

```js
type Example = {
  name?: string;
  [item: string]?: unknown; // error: TS1131: Property or signature expected.
};
```

Comment: Can you post the error it outputs?

Comment: `TS1131: Property or signature expected.`

Comment: `[item: string]: unknown;` already implies that these items are optional.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could create a type for the dynamic item and make it optional using `Partial` like below.

```
type DynamicItemtype = { 
  [item: string]: unknown;
}
```

Then add both types into another type as an `intersection type` like

```
type Example = {
  name?: string
}

type CombinedTypes = Example & Partial<DynamicItemtype>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [type utilities](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) `Partial` and `Record` to create the type you want:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQAoIE7ACWCqAPAEoQDGA9ngCakDOwehAdgOYA0UAruwDW7GgHd2APglQAZFADeUdsggB+AFxQWbLlAC+AbgCwAKFP1qqfNFrsWUCIhTpN8ZGgjGTj9+gB0ykieUAD0IVqsHJxQAD787BYAZhwQ9KY+zhB+COwgAPLAABYQeNh4NJAEIAah4QLCYuymQA)

```ts
type Example = Partial<Record<string, unknown>> & { name?: string };

declare const example: Example;
example.name; // string | undefined
example.anyOtherProperty; // unknown
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you

Comment: `Partial<Record<string, unknown>>` is the exact same type as  `Record<string, unknown>` and your `type Example` is still `{ name?: string; [item: string]: unknown; }`

Comment: @Thomas That's true when the optional type is `unknown` (because anything other than `any` in a union with `unknown` becomes `unknown`). However, I used `Partial` in the answer to provide a pattern to follow for creating an object with _optional_ property types. [If the type were anything other than `any` or `unknown`](https://tsplay.dev/NVaOvw), it would be required in order to be correct.

Comment: @etoxin I'm curious: in what type of scenario are you actually using this pattern?

Comment: Was curiosity actually. There was nothing on SO.